# Derivation of posterior predictive distribution for autoregressive model

Tags: self-study, bayesian

[Bayesian Choice ex. 1.37]

If $x \sim N(\theta, \sigma^2)$ and $y \sim N(\rho x, \sigma^2)$, as in an autoregressive mode, with $\rho$ known, and $\pi(\theta, \sigma^2) = 1/\sigma^2$, give the predictive distribution of $y$ given $x$.

My attempt:

$p(y|x) = \int \int  f(y|x, \theta, \sigma)\pi(\theta, \sigma | x) d\theta d\sigma^2$

$\pi(\theta, \sigma | x) \propto \exp (-(\theta - x)^2/\sigma^2 )/\sigma^3 $

so $p(y|x) \propto \int \int  \exp(-(y - \rho x)^2/2\sigma^2)\exp(-(x - \theta )^2/2\sigma^2)/\sigma^4 d\theta d\sigma^2 $

But how do you evaluate the integral?

Update,

$\int   \exp(-(y - \rho x)^2/2\sigma^2)/\sigma^4  \underbrace{\int \exp(-(x - \theta )^2/2\sigma^2)d\theta}_{\propto \sigma} d\sigma^2 \propto$

$\int   \exp(-(y - \rho x)^2/2\sigma^2)/\sigma^3 d\sigma^2 \propto$

$1 / (y - \rho x)$, which is not proper

Comment: Thanks, I tried again, can you check my last three lines?

Comment: Try to make the substitution in the integral $z=1/\sigma^2$ and then identify a gamma  distribution, you can evaluate the integral after. It must give a t distribution I think

Comment: This is the correct answer: with a single observation and an improper prior, the predictive is not defined.

Comment: This is a problem in Christian Robert book The Bayesian Choice. I don't think he would have asked a predictive if it didn't exIst.